# ActionBar update in switching between fragments

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I search for solution for my problem , but didn't find exactly what I want . I hope you can help.

I implemented list in Fragment , by click the list a detail fragment wanted to be add .
the list fragment has its action bar buttons while the detail has another action bar buttons.

the detail is implemented in pager. where the pager fragment load a fragment
Also , the list is a fragment in Navigation Drawer

the hirarachy is 
Navigation Drawer >> List fragment >> page fragment >> detail fragment

I used add fragment when click from list to page , because I don't want reload whn I back to the list as happened when I use replace.

My problem is 
the action bar buttons are not updated when I back to the list . it keeps the buttons of detail fragments

List Fragment . on item click

```
 PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();



public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
            { 
                getActivity().onBackPressed();

                return true;

            }
```

this is the backPressed in Navigation drawer activity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
      Log.i("Main ","Back pressed");

       mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

    }
```

on Page fragment and detail fragment I override options as following

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
            { 
                getActivity().onBackPressed();

                return true;

            }
}
```

Do I am doing right? and how can I solve the action bar buttons problem 
when I back to list

thanks in advance

Comment: You should use `NavUtils` rather than manually calling `onBackPressed()` or the FragmentManager to pop the backstack.

Comment: I tried pop the backstack of fragment manager and get the same result

Answer (score 0):

invalidateOptionsMenu will cause the options menu to be redrawn. perhaps some clever use of this method, coupled with onResume in your activity will solve your issue.

Comment: could you give more explanation about use onResume? what to be used in this method ?

Comment: Basically, you need to detect when your activity comes back into the foreground, onResume is a method of Activity called when the activity becomes visible to the user again. When the frag is removed, the activity resumes, rebuilt the options menu there. http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-iAh-GvmfHU0/UMnUEcPv2cI/AAAAAAAAALk/cZlh4kMEzNo/s1600/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: I got that meaning , can you tell me how can I rebuild the options menu? can I call the method? what arguments to be send as menu?

Comment: Make a call to invalidateOptionMenu(), its a method of Activity. No paramenters needed.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem . I added supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() in OnResum in my navigation drawer activity and also in list fragment.. nothing change, did I miss something?

Comment: seems invalidateOptions doesn't do what is needed . I used it in a sure reached code where log is printed but it doesn't affect the code